# Two printers on Windows 7 with different settings?

Tags: printing

I want to create two different print settings so that with one click I can choose to print landscape/legal or portrait/letter. I'm using Windows 7.

I'm trying several different approaches to get this to work. None of them seems to work:

Approach 1: Two separate printer profiles pointing to the same printer.  It simply sets the preferences to the last ones used rather than the ones specific to that printer.

Approach 2. Two different printers (yes I went to the length of buying a second printer). Even though prefereneces are different for each printer, when I switch printers it simply sets the preferences to the last ones used rather than the ones specific to that printer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel > Printers > Install new printer. All you have to do is install a "virtual" printer by giving your "new" printer
a different name, quite likely something that would indicate the settings you intend to use it with, but choosing the
same port and same driver as your old one. I have about 8 virtual printers installed, which are all the same printer
with different settings made for each. I get them all to choose from in any application which shows the menu of installed printers.
This works on Windows XP and Vista, I would be astonished if it did not on 7.

Comment: I have done exactly that on Windows 7 and on XP - the problem is that when I print from the browser it always defaults to the settings of the default printer. Is there any way you have found around this?

Comment: It looks like there was a bug in Chrome 21 that was impacting printing (was not recognizing printer settings). I reverted to Chrome 20 on oldapps.com and now things work fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just install your printer twice - you can even pick another driver for each of them
2. Right-Click them, choose `Printer Properties`, got to tab `Advanced` and click on the button `Printing Defaults...` at the left bottom of the window
3. Set your printing preferences

This will set the default printing preferences for your printers. Even clients will have the same settings if they connected your shared printers.

*Note:* You may have to set your printing preferences *also* like this:

1. Right-Click your printer
2. Click `Printing Preferences`
3. Set your printing preferences

Windows always keeps previous printing preferences and setting them like I described first doesn't override those temporary saved settings. Only the second process will override them. 
If you don't plan to share your printers you just need to do the second method I described.

Comment: The problem is that when I print from the browser it always defaults to the settings of the default printer. Is there any way you have found around this?

Comment: that is not normal behaviour. That shouldn't happen if you followed my steps. What browser do you use? Does that problem also occur in other applications?